# Assign one docker instance to each client

Tags: python, docker, webserver

I have a docker instance that exposes a port A to the host. The host reserves a port B for the docker instance, and a client connecting to port B on the host will actually be communicating to the docker on port A without knowing it.

Currently, only one client can access this docker instance. I want to be able to manage multiple clients, each of them having its own instance. So the server (Python would be fine) would receive connections from clients on a port (e.g. port 5555 for *all* the clients) and redirect each client to its own docker instance seamlessly.

This has to already exist, because it is basic stuff for a server, but I seem to lack the vocabulary to find it online. What is the name of such a system, and does one already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really need is a proxy server that will listen to port A. When a client connects to port A she/he will be redirected to port B without noticing it. An example would be an docker apache server that will listen to port 80 and forward all request to another server e.g tomcat that listens to port 8080. Eg.

```
docker run --name tomcat run -d tomcat
docker run -v path/to/your/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf --name proxy -d --link tomcat:tomcatserver -p 80:80 httpd
```

Your httpd.conf should look something like this:

```
# Put this after the other LoadModule directives
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://tomcatserver:8080
ProxyPassReverse / http://tomcatserver:8080
<Location />
     Require all granted
</Location>
```

Yyj y y 5 yep ptpy